# JBoss AS 7 auto deploy plugin cannot connect to localhost:8080

Tags: java, deployment, maven, jboss, jboss7.x

I have configured the plugin in maven as shown below:

```
<plugin>
                <groupId>org.jboss.as.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>jboss-as-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>7.0.2.Final</version>
                <configuration>
                    <hostname>localhost</hostname>
                    <port>8080</port>
                    <filename>target/TestApp.war</filename>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>deploy</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
</plugin>
```

I then trigger it using maven using

```
mvn -U clean install package
```

It does build and everything works fine but fails when it starts the auto deployment.

```
INFO]
INFO] --- jboss-as-maven-plugin:7.0.2.Final:deploy (default) @ TestApp ---
INFO] Executing goal deploy on server localhost (127.0.0.1) port 8080.
9-Feb-2012 16:18:46 org.jboss.remoting3.EndpointImpl <clinit>
NFO: JBoss Remoting version 3.2.0.Beta2
9-Feb-2012 16:18:46 org.xnio.Xnio <clinit>
NFO: XNIO Version 3.0.0.Beta2
9-Feb-2012 16:18:46 org.xnio.nio.NioXnio <clinit>
NFO: XNIO NIO Implementation Version 3.0.0.Beta2
INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
INFO] BUILD FAILURE
INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
INFO] Total time: 58.768s
INFO] Finished at: Thu Feb 09 16:18:52 GMT 2012
INFO] Final Memory: 7M/18M
INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.jboss.as.plugins:jboss-as-maven-plugin:7.0.2.Final:deploy (default) on project TestApp: Could not execute goal deploy on TestApp.war. Reason: Could not connect to remote://localhost:8080 in 5000ms. Make sure the server is running and/or consider setting a longer timeout by setting -Dorg.jboss.as.client.connect.timeout=<timeout in ms>. -> [Help 1]
ERROR]
ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
ERROR]
```

The error seems to suggest that it could not connect to the application server on localhost:8080. It is running and i can access it. Any ideas?

JBoss Application Server version is 7.0.2
Maven version is 3.0.4

Answer (score 5, accepted):

By default port 8080 is not the management port. The plugin requires you to use the management which is 9999 by default.

Also your filename element isn't quite right. Adding target at the beginning will cause the file not to be found.

The plugin looks in the build directory by default for the file name. In most cases the filename element doesn't even need to be used. The plugin will assume the file name is the `${project.build.finalName}.${project.packaging}` by default, which will likely work in your case.

Assuming you haven't changed the default management port you'd want it to look something like this.

```
<plugin>
            <groupId>org.jboss.as.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>jboss-as-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>7.0.2.Final</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <phase>package</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>deploy</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
</plugin>
```

Comment: Thanks @James. You were right i was using the wrong port number. And you were right about the filename too as i had to change that as you described. - Thanks

Answer (score 4):

According to this [page](https://github.com/jbossas/jboss-as-maven-plugin), you should not specify the web port (8080), but the administration port (defaults to 9999), which is the one used for deployments.

Answer (score 0):

I had a very similar situation and solved it by simply editing `standalone.xml` file to add a proper `socket-binding` for management interface.

You can check out more at [my blog](http://www.eloquentcoder.com/2015/11/08/configure-jboss-for-maven-deployments/).